# How to add and customize an element on title page of a beamer template

Tags: beamer, titles, layout

I'd like to add an extra element to the title page of a beamer template. I've tried re-purposing and re-positioning the `\institute{}` element for this, but moving it down causes the height of the page to increase. For example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis} % Use metropolis theme
\setbeamertemplate{institute}{
    \vspace*{6em}
    \insertinstitute%
    \par%
}
\title{A minimal example}
\date{\today}
\author{Matthias Vogelgesang}
\date{}
\institute{I want the new element here}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

How do I add an element that sits somewhere at the bottom left corner of the page while retaining the page height set by the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add an overlay `tikzpicture` wherever you like.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{metropolis} % Use metropolis theme
\setbeamertemplate{institute}{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node[anchor=south west] at (current page.south west){\insertinstitute};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\title{A minimal example}
\author{Matthias Vogelgesang}
\date{}
\institute{I want the new element here}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the original answer, but I wonder how I can make the new element with line breaks such that it can span across multiple lines (and with different amounts of spacing between the lines)? I've tried using `\newline` within the `\institute{}` element but it does not work

Comment: @Skyork You need to dial an alignment, e.g. align=center, and add this to the node options. Then you can use \\ in order to insert a line break.

Comment: that works. Thanks again!